# how to make a row in jtable nonselectable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am first time using jtable. How can I make a particular row in jtable cannot be selected again after an action is performed. I tried `setRowSelectionAllowed(boolean)` method, but it applied to all the rows.

Comment: Call upon the great javadoc for JTable and TableModel and all shall be revealed!

Comment: Hint : isCellEditable

Comment: @Thihara also non editable cell can be selected.

Comment: But what is the reason for making particular row not selectable. B'coz it is in display so a user can select it. I'm not getting the reason for doing it. Can you please explain why?

Comment: @AudriusMeškauskas Oops my fault for mistaking the two and not paying close attention to the question...

Answer (score 1):

Set the table selection model to the list selection model that disallows selection of the forbidden rows:

```
class RestrictedSelector extends DefaultListSelectionModel {

  HashSet<Integer> forbiddenRows = new HashSet<Integer>();

  @Override
  public void addSelectionInterval(int index0, int index1) {
    for (int row = index0; row <= index1; row++) {
       if (forbiddenRows.contains(row)) {
         // You can also have more complex code to select still
         // valid rows here.
         return;
       }
    }
  }

 // Implement these in the same spirit:

 public void insertIndexInterval(int index0, int index1) 
 ...
 public void setSelectionInterval(int index0, int index1) 
 ...
 public void setLeadSelectionIndex(int leadIndex)      
 ...

 // and others, see below.
}
```

Check [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListSelectionModel.html) for all methods that must be overridden.

Now:

```
RestrictedSelector selector = new RestrictedSelector();

selector.forbiddenRows.add(NOT_THIS_ROW_1);
selector.forbiddenRows.add(NOT_THIS_ROW_2);

myTable.setSelectionModel(selector);
```

If your table rows are sortable, you may also need to use `convertRowIndexToModel` and `convertRowIndexToView` as probably it is the row number in the model, not in the table, that must be banned from being selected.