# JTable row selection from the end

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane

Happy New Year for everyone! :)

I have a `JTable` inside `JScrollPane` (`fillsViewportHeight` is `true`) and want to enable row selection from the end when drag starts outside the table (as shown on the pic)
[image]

**SSCCE:**

```
public class SimpleTableDemo extends JPanel {

    public SimpleTableDemo() {
        super(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

        String[] columnNames = { "First Name", "Last Name", "Sport", "# of Years", "Vegetarian" };

        Object[][] data = { { "Kathy", "Smith", "Snowboarding", new Integer(5), new Boolean(false) }, { "John", "Doe", "Rowing", new Integer(3), new Boolean(true) }, { "Sue", "Black", "Knitting", new Integer(2), new Boolean(false) }, { "Jane", "White", "Speed reading", new Integer(20), new Boolean(true) }, { "Joe", "Brown", "Pool", new Integer(10), new Boolean(false) } };

        final JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames);
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 70));
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

        add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SimpleTableDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(700, 400);

        SimpleTableDemo newContentPane = new SimpleTableDemo();
        newContentPane.setOpaque(true);
        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

How can I do that?

**UPD:**

The **default behavior** of `JTable` is to select all rows from start to current one, if I start selection lower the last row. **I want** to select only that rows which was under the mouse while I've dragged the mouse up (as I've shown in picture).

Comment: whats happends in the case that you set  [ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#selection), default value is `MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION`

Comment: 1. you have to use SINGLE_...,  2. question you wan to select all rows from one selected row to the end of JTables view (in this case doeasn't matter if is sorted or filtered, selection is only about JTables view), e.g. then selection  to 1st row to select all rows in JTable, it's true???  3. do you want to store this selection in SelectionModel

Comment: can you use the approach shown in [how to make a row in jtable nonselectable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15586118/how-to-make-a-row-in-jtable-nonselectable)

Comment: @mKorbel 1. I said, it changes nothing; 2. *sorry I don't understand what you mean*; 3. Yes, of course.

Comment: @trashgod thanks, but it is not what I mean

Comment: table.setRowSelectionInterval(table.getRowCount() - 1, table.getRowCount() - 1); and by reseting
        table.removeRowSelectionInterval(table.getRowCount() - 1, table.getRowCount() - 1); ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ingredients:

- a mouseListener detecting the mousePressed "below" the last row
- if so, set the anchor of the row selection model to the last row

Something like:

```
MouseListener l = new MouseAdapter() {

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        Rectangle lastRow = table.getCellRect(table.getRowCount() - 1, 0, false);
        if (e.getY() < lastRow.y + lastRow.height) return;
        System.out.println(table);
        table.getSelectionModel().setAnchorSelectionIndex(table.getRowCount()-1);
    }

};
table.addMouseListener(l);
```

Comment: Thank U... but can you please explain why does it work?

Comment: @SeniorJD don't understand what you want explained - couldn't do any better than the api doc ... hint, hint ;-)